# How to disable touch bar in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

How can I deactivate Touch Bar in Sublime Text 3 on Macbook Pro OS X?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Navigate to
***Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Settings***
, and add this to the User Preferences:

```
{
    "show_navigation_bar": false
}
```

[image]
[image: User Preferences]